# gulp cannot find semantic.json during installation of semantic-ui

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, semantic-ui, gulp-less

I'm trying to install semantic-ui using npm and gulp using this tutorial: http://www.semantic-ui.com/introduction/getting-started.html

I run `npm install semantic-ui --save` and everything's fine.
but then I direct into `semantic/` folder and run `gulp build` but is says:

```
cannot find semantic.json. Run "gulp install" to set-up Semantic
```

the `semantic.json` file is on the root of my project. I also tried `gulp install` but it says `Task 'install' is not in your gulpfile`

what should I do?

EDIT: 
this is my gulpfile.js file:

```
/*******************************
            Set-up
*******************************/

var
  gulp         = require('gulp-help')(require('gulp')),

  // read user config to know what task to load
  config       = require('./tasks/config/user'),

  // watch changes
  watch        = require('./tasks/watch'),

  // build all files
  build        = require('./tasks/build'),
  buildJS      = require('./tasks/build/javascript'),
  buildCSS     = require('./tasks/build/css'),
  buildAssets  = require('./tasks/build/assets'),

  // utility
  clean        = require('./tasks/clean'),
  version      = require('./tasks/version'),

  // docs tasks
  serveDocs    = require('./tasks/docs/serve'),
  buildDocs    = require('./tasks/docs/build'),

  // rtl
  buildRTL     = require('./tasks/rtl/build'),
  watchRTL     = require('./tasks/rtl/watch')
;


/*******************************
             Tasks
*******************************/

gulp.task('default', false, [
  'watch'
]);

gulp.task('watch', 'Watch for site/theme changes', watch);

gulp.task('build', 'Builds all files from source', build);
gulp.task('build-javascript', 'Builds all javascript from source', buildJS);
gulp.task('build-css', 'Builds all css from source', buildCSS);
gulp.task('build-assets', 'Copies all assets from source', buildAssets);

gulp.task('clean', 'Clean dist folder', clean);
gulp.task('version', 'Displays current version of Semantic', version);

/*--------------
      Docs
---------------*/

/*
  Lets you serve files to a local documentation instance
  https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-Docs/
*/

gulp.task('serve-docs', 'Serve file changes to SUI Docs', serveDocs);
gulp.task('build-docs', 'Build all files and add to SUI Docs', buildDocs);


/*--------------
      RTL
---------------*/

if(config.rtl) {
  gulp.task('watch-rtl', 'Build all files as RTL', watchRTL);
  gulp.task('build-rtl', 'Watch files as RTL ', buildRTL);
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? are you running `gulp build` from `npm_modules/semantic`?
also add your `gulpfile.js` so we can assist

Comment: I'm trying to install and use semantic-ui in a project. I'm running `gulp build` from `myproject/semantic`

Comment: are you trying to add `semantic-ui` to your existing project?

Comment: yes, I'm adding it to an existing django project

Comment: iv'e tried to do `npm install semantic-ui` and i see what you meant. have you considered using `bower`?

Comment: can I use bower on windows?

Answer (score 6):

This problem happens when the `node_modules` is located in the upstream or different folder. Let's say you install the `semantic-ui` globally and the `node_modules` is located in:

`/Users/afshin/node_modules/`

All you need to address this issue is to copy the `node_modules` to the `semantic-ui` folder (your semantic-ui project folder)

Hope this save someone from a headache.

Comment: I lost you, where to copy the `node_modules` from?

Comment: @JikkuJose you can find the `node_modules` in upstream folders.

Answer (score 4):

> I run npm install semantic-ui --save and everything's fine. **but then I direct into `semantic/` folder and `run gulp` build** ...

iv'e tried to follow up your lead and executed `npm install semantic-ui`

i got this annoying wizard:

[image]

## Why not `bower`?

Since all you care about is to referencing `semantic-ui`'s static files, i suggest [using `bower`](http://bower.io/)

**install `bower`:**

`npm install -g bower`

**then add `semantic-ui`:**

`bower install semantic-ui`

---

The `semantic-ui` package includes a [`dist`](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/tree/master/dist) directory contains a build of `js` + `css` ready to use

Comment: I tried to use `gulp` because it has an `update` command. Can I update my semantic-ui with bower too?